# Is there a way to create a bigger block of code in Javascript switching text with clicks?

Tags: javascript, html

I have came up with a string of codes to show educational text in dependence of what the viewer clicks.  Eventually I will attach images too. 
Being a newbie however I do believe it can be done in a much neater way. Also considering there will be like 30 options. I wish to use a key variable to turn on and off depending on a route the viewer choose and this way cut down on the functions and attachevent events.

To reiterate the goal of my program is to show various text depending on what button is clicked. Like Route A, Route B and then Route A1,2 Route B1,2 etc.

```
<html>

<body>

<div id="DivTextBox">Here is Intro of the story! <br><br><br><br><br><br><br> TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTe
xtTextTextTextTextTextText <br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>

<div id="bint">
<button id="ButtonA">
Option A
</button>
<button id="ButtonB">
Option B
</button>
</div>
<button id="hideButtons">
 Hide Buttons
 </button>
 <button id="showButtons">
 Show Buttons
 </button>

 <script>

turncount = 0;
chA = document.getElementById("ButtonA");
chB = document.getElementById("ButtonB");
PrnKey = "Intro";
hideButtons.onclick = () => {
    bint.style.display = 'none';
}
showButtons.onclick = () => {
    bint.style.display = 'inline';

}
DivTextBox.onclick = () => {
bint.style.display = 'inline';
};


document.getElementById("ButtonA").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("DivTextBox").innerHTML = "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Text explaining Option A<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
    turncount ++;
    bint.style.display = 'none';
    ButtonA.innerText = `Option A turn ${turncount}`;
    ButtonB.innerText = `Option B turn ${turncount}`;
    chA.id = ("a1A");
    chB.id = ("a1B");
    attachEventHandlersRouteA();
    };
function attachEventHandlersRouteA() {

  document.getElementById("a1A").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("DivTextBox").innerHTML = "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Text explaining Option a1A<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";

    turncount++;
      bint.style.display = 'none';
      a1A.innerText = `Option a1A turn ${turncount}`;
      a1B.innerText = `Option a1B turn ${turncount}`;
  };

  document.getElementById("a1B").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("DivTextBox").innerHTML = "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Text explaining Option a1B<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";

    turncount++;
    bint.style.display = 'none';
    a1A.innerText = `Option bA turn ${turncount}`;
    a1B.innerText = `Option bB turn ${turncount}`;
    };

}



document.getElementById("ButtonB").onclick = function () {
    bint.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("DivTextBox").innerHTML = "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Text explaining Option B<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
    turncount ++;
    ButtonA.innerText = `Option bA turn ${turncount}`;
    ButtonB.innerText = `Option bB turn ${turncount}`;
    chA.id = ("b1A");
    chB.id = ("b1B");
    attachEventHandlersRouteB ();
    };

function attachEventHandlersRouteB() {

  document.getElementById("b1A").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("DivTextBox").innerHTML = "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Text explaining Option b1A<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";

    turncount++;
      bint.style.display = 'none';
      b1A.innerText = `Option b1A turn ${turncount}`;
      b1B.innerText = `Option b1B turn ${turncount}`;
  };

  document.getElementById("b1B").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("DivTextBox").innerHTML = "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Text explaining Option b1B<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
    turncount++;
    bint.style.display = 'none';
    b1A.innerText = `Option b1A turn ${turncount}`;
    b1B.innerText = `Option b1B turn ${turncount}`;
    };

}


 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You may need to explain the overall concept a little more clearly. Is it a drill-down question/answer thing? Judging by the code here, I see what looks like lots of duplication, which I'm sure can be improved. All those br tags are really bad, use CSS instead to get spacing.

Comment: The CSS does not work for some reason. I think that is not the most important thing.

Comment: Of course the CSS isn't the key thing, but cleaning the code makes it more readable. I think in terms of code you're approaching this in the wrong way, it looks too specific rather than being an abstracted algorithm. I still don't fully understand what you are trying to do. From what you've said I think you need to look at setting up a data structure that supports organisation of stages, maybe XML or JSON. It looks like you need something that supports nesting easily. Then look at a method of traversing that data and providing buttons and answers for each stage in the data.

Comment: Even traversing the HTML DOM can be beneficial, look at jQuery which makes this much easier. Maybe think about setting up a variable to store your current position (as a ref to a DOM element), then using jQuery to find child elements of that dom element which can be shown/hidden etc. Also, look at delegated events.